# wake-up by the computer

Tags: bios, wake-up

some time ago(10 years back) I've read on PC Magazine that some mainboards have some settings which allow to a computer to open at a certain hour. I need to make my computer to wake me up in each morning. How can I do that ? What MB settings allow this feature?

ps: i will like to shout down the computer during the night(not sleep or hibernate mode). ATM I'm using windows xp and 7 on my computers.

Comment: +1. Looking into this myself, as I need to start powering down my PC at night. It is drawing too much power. I will answer if I find a working result.

Comment: Scheduled Tasks .. maybe

Comment: Do you want the PC to start at a certain time in the morning, or to use the PC as an alarm clock (to wake you up), or both?

Comment: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaperformance/thread/d50ed04b-f520-4913-a4d7-d22ea8cf302e

Comment: Add to the comment of jjj a pretty obnoxious Windows-start music, and the deed is done.

Comment: @doug Apple computers have this feature out of the box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most BIOS have [an option](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock_alarm) to wake the computer up at a defined time. This option is usually named "Resume by alarm" or "Wake-up on RTC", something like this (not wake on lan, though, this is [something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_on_LAN)).

You can find more details about it at [this article](http://www.inspectmygadget.com/2009/01/08/little-known-bios-features-wake-up-a-computer-on-a-schedule/).

[image: resume by alarm bios screenshot]

*Nb: You can find a list of keys to enter the BIOS setup [at this page](http://michaelstevenstech.com/bios_manufacturer.htm). It should however be written in a corner when booting the computer.*