# Schedule PC booting

Tags: boot, scheduled-tasks

I just want to schedule my PC boot up time.I mean @ morning 9:30 it should boot up automatically
I am using windows xp

Comment: possible duplicate of [wake-up by the computer](http://superuser.com/questions/145420/wake-up-by-the-computer) (though this one has a clearer title)

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your system BIOS there should be the option to power on by "RTC", simply set the time and it should fire up automatically each day.

Answer (score 1):

If your PC supports [wake-on-RTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTC_Alarm) you can create a Windows scheduled task which does something innocuous like `cmd.exe /c exit` (which will briefly flash up a command prompt) and in the Settings tab check "Wake the computer to run this task".